# Searching and Inserting in a map with 3 elements in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I need to have a map like this :

```
typedef std::map<int, float , char> Maptype ;
```

What is the syntax to insert and searching elements of pair  in this map.

Comment: Which one(s) is/are the key(s)?

Comment: Please check you are not getting confused here. A map can have a third element in it, if it's an ordering command.

Answer (score 20):

A `map` can only map one key type to one data type. If the data contains 2 elements, use a struct or a `std::pair`.

```
typedef std::map<int, std::pair<float, char> > Maptype;
...
Maptype m;
m[123] = std::make_pair(0.5f, 'c');
...
std::pair<float, char> val = m[245];
std::cout << "float: " << val.first << ", char: " << val.second << std::endl;
```

Comment: Avoid copying the pair out of the map by assigning a reference:
std::pair<float, char> & val = m[245];

Answer (score 9):

You cannot have three elements. The STL `map` stores a key-value pair. You need to decide on what you are going to use as a key. Once done, you can probably nest the other two in a separate map and use it as:

```
typedef std::map<int, std::map<float, char> > MapType;
```

In order to insert in a map, use the `operator[]` or the `insert` member function. You can search for using the `find` member function.

```
MapType m;
// insert
m.insert(std::make_pair(4, std::make_pair(3.2, 'a')));
m[ -4 ] = make_pair(2.4, 'z');
// fnd
MapType::iterator i = m.find(-4);
if (i != m.end()) { // item exists ...
}
```

Additionally you can look at [Boost.Tuple](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html).

Comment: Thanks for info . How do I search for the pair in Map .
Will it be m.find(STD::make_pair(3.2,'a');  ?

Comment: @John: You search for the key, always. If your key is of type `pair<float, char>` then that is what you pass as argument to `map::find`. Note, in a map, the first parameter is the key, the second is the key's value. Either, can be a complex type. However, the key is always `const` and can not be assigned to.

Comment: @dirkgently: The above example doesn't work, if I use two class pointer instance and a string. like typedef std::map<std::string ethname, std::map<consumer_class *, producer_class *> >

Answer (score 7):

Use either

```
std::map<std::pair<int, float>, char>
```

or

```
std::map<int, std::pair<float, char> >
```

whichever is correct.

Comment: Note that the former would need either an overloaded `operator<` or a function object for sorting passed to the map.

Comment: std::pair already has operator< (it does lexicographical comparison).