# std::map insert another map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2392104/1729501) and wrote below code. But it gives below compilation error. I think it's because make_pair cannot accept another make_pair as an argument. What is the alternative then?

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::map<float, int>
>::insert(std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, std::pair<double, int> >)’
```

code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::map<float, int> > map1;
    std::string string1 = "alpha";
    map1.insert(std::make_pair(string1, std::make_pair(1.1, 1)));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're attempting here, but the inaccuracy of floating point arthmetic makes maps with floating point keys tricky to handle.

Comment: @john I am making a map of floats and ints. Later I want to search inside the map for a particular float value. Are you advising that map isn't right for this task?

Comment: You have to be careful that your floating point values are *accurate*. Depending on the calculations you are doing this may not be easy. I'm not saying it's definitely wrong, just that there are pitfalls. You could add 0.1 to your map but then when you search you might have 0.09999999999999999, and the search will fail.

Comment: @user13107 john is quite-accurate. you can do it, but you need a fairly smart comparator that *may* have to account for inaccuracies, literally "close enough" so-to-speak. For example. inserting a key `1.1`, then searching for a *computed* `key = 1.0 + 0.1` may surprise you.

Comment: @john and WhozCraig what map alternative do you suggest?

Comment: @user13107 you can still use a map, you just need to understand how floats compare and may need a custom key comparator for what you're trying to do. If you're never read it before, read this when you get a chance: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Its long, but worth it, and a real eye-opener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you can use the `[]` operator as follows:

```
map1[string1][1.1] =  1;
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if this was going to work, so I tried it out in Visual Studio before posting. Thanks though! :)

Answer (score 3):

Your initializing the second half of your "pair" with something that isn't a map.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::map<float, int> > map1;
    std::string string1 = "alpha";
    std::map<float,int> mapsub;
    mapsub.insert(std::make_pair(1.1, 1));
    map1.insert(std::make_pair(string1, mapsub));
    return 0;
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::map<float, int> > map1;
    std::string string1 = "alpha";
    map1.insert(std::make_pair(string1, std::map<float,int>{std::make_pair(1.1,1)}));
    return 0;
}
```