# std::unordered_multimap - mapping 3 elements to one key

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map, multimap

My question is an extension of the following question:
[Searching and Inserting in a map with 3 elements in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392093/searching-and-inserting-in-a-map-with-3-elements-in-c)

In addition to the above-mentioned case, I would like to have an extra pair in map as given below definition.

```
std::unordered_multimap<unsigned int, 
      std::pair< std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, float>> wedgeAlphaMap;
```

This does not work well. 
All the time when I emplace values for the second variable in the pair(i.e. vi2), I  am getting a garbage value.
(code shown below)

```
wedgeAlphaMap.emplace(vi0, std::make_pair(std::make_pair(vi1,vi2), alpha) );
```

This is how I am getting(note: the vi2 for all)

```
vi0: 2762     vi1:2758       vi2:0     Alpha:90.0000 
vi0: 2762     vi1:2761       vi2:-1610612736     Alpha:11.2407 
vi0: 2762     vi1:2763       vi2:-536870912     Alpha:78.7593 
vi0: 2762     vi1:2767       vi2:1073741824     Alpha:50.4362 
vi0: 2762     vi1:2759       vi2:-1073741824     Alpha:39.5638 
vi0: 2762     vi1:2769       vi2:0     Alpha:90.0000 
vi0: 40     vi1:1       vi2:-1610612736     Alpha:67.5731 
vi0: 40     vi1:41       vi2:-2147483648     Alpha:67.5728 
vi0: 40     vi1:35       vi2:0     Alpha:90.0000 
vi0: 40     vi1:375       vi2:1073741824     Alpha:48.3076 
vi0: 40     vi1:376       vi2:-1073741824     Alpha:41.6924
and so on...................................
```

Printing before emplacing them to the map:

```
The vi0: 40 , vi1: 1 , vi2: 376
The vi0: 1 , vi1: 376 , vi2: 40
The vi0: 376 , vi1: 40 , vi2: 1
The vi0: 376 , vi1: 1 , vi2: 377
The vi0: 1 , vi1: 377 , vi2: 376
The vi0: 377 , vi1: 376 , vi2: 1
The vi0: 3 , vi1: 195 , vi2: 193
The vi0: 195 , vi1: 193 , vi2: 3
The vi0: 193 , vi1: 3 , vi2: 195
The vi0: 193 , vi1: 195 , vi2: 194
The vi0: 195 , vi1: 194 , vi2: 193
The vi0: 194 , vi1: 193 , vi2: 195
The vi0: 97 , vi1: 5 , vi2: 98
The vi0: 5 , vi1: 98 , vi2: 97
The vi0: 98 , vi1: 97 , vi2: 5
The vi0: 98 , vi1: 5 , vi2: 99
The vi0: 5 , vi1: 99 , vi2: 98
The vi0: 99 , vi1: 98 , vi2: 5
and so on...................................
```

How I can properly make use of it/ or do I have missed something?

Comment: Try to print out values you are emplacing (`vi2`) to see if they have garbage values there. BTW, why don't you use `std::tuple` instead of `pair` of `pair`?

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/mwQEQ) is a handy chart of bugs that can appear in stackoverflow questions. Handmade by yours truly, enjoy.

Comment: @DanielLangr : Yes I have printed the values before emplacing. That was correct. But while emplacing, that's not getting correctly emplacing.

Comment: @n.m. why do you think, its handmaid? I really did not get your point?.

Comment: I have made the chart by hand. More specifically I took some markers and have drawn it on a whiteboard and photographed it, as opposed to using a drawing program.

Comment: Have you tried with insert? I suspect you are hitting the limited support for emplace in c++11, improved in c++14. The syntax you have may be c++14. In c++11 you would need to use piecewise_construct, perhaps?

Comment: @Jackyone Can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: @DanielLangr could you please tell me, how I can rewrite with std:: tuple... I tried but got confused with accessing from the map.

Comment: @DanielLangr what do you mean by minimal working example?

Comment: Hello all, my aim is to map `pair( pair(integer, integer), float)` to an `integer key` in a unsorterd_multimap... Don't need to be the way I mentioned here if you got some idea also comment/ answer here.

Comment: Also I think I need a hash function to do this. Just have very little idea about it. guessing though.

Comment: @DanielLangr here found one example for it, but how I can access the second values one by one?

Comment: @Jackyone See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. To help you, we need some code to work with that generates your problem.

Comment: @Jackyone `std::tuple` is (from C++11) a generalized `std::pair` to an arbitrary number of elements. You can use `std::tuple<int, int, float>` instead of `std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, float>`. Of course, you need to provide a hasher for such `tuple`, since C++ Standard library doesn't define one. But this is also true for `pair`. Boost can help here.